# Is It Possible To Impersonate Another Person Within The Force?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

As we've seen in the movies, we know that Force users are capable of identifying one another by simply feeling their presence.  Amongst other examples, Luke felt Darth Vader's presence on the way to Endor, and Vader felt Obi-Wan's presence on the Death Star.  In each of the on-screen instances, the person was immediately and explicitly identified and known by the one that sensed them.

Additionally, we know that it is possible for a Force user to mask their power and hide themselves from other Force users. Darth Sidious hid himself in plain sight as he manipulated his way through the Senate.  Master Yoda exiled himself to Dagobah to "cover-up" his own Force "radiance" with the Living Force (and powerful Dark side influence) of the planet and its inhabitants to hide himself while he prepared himself for what was to come.

However, as I was editing [another of my questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115773/can-kylo-ren-actually-communicate-with-darth-vader), I began to wonder if it is possible for a Force practitioner to somehow impersonate someone else's (for lack of a better term) Force "signature".  For example (to use characters from Episode VII), would it be possible (whether or not it would be useful) for Supreme Leader Snoke to somehow present himself - whether visibly, audibly or any other way - to Kylo Ren as the spirit of Darth Vader without Kylo Ren being able to detect the deception?  Possibly some sort of long-range Jedi mind-trick?  Has any such ability been manifested in any of the current canon or Legends/EU?

Comment: How did Darth Vader know what Obi-Wan was getting for Christmas?... He felt his presents (presence).  :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On second thought, in season 6 of Star Wars: The Clone Wars, the Palpatine and Dooku were able to create a long distance rendering of Sifo Dyas, and it convinced Yoda that it was actually Sifo Dyas. Assuming that Yoda is always perceptive of the force, it is logical to assume that the Sith Lords were creating a false aura around Sifo Dyas, although Yoda had an idea that it was a trick.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be edited into your first answer?

Comment: I really need to watch the whole TCW series.  Even though I've really enjoyed them, I've only seen a couple of episodes because every time I try, something comes up that prevents me from watching more.  Since this is apparently a full-on canon example of what I was talking about, I'm switching my acceptance.  Thank you for this info.

Answer (score 2):

If a force user were powerful enough and combined the techniques of masking oneself's force signature and a powerful mind trick, it could be possible to impersonate another force user. However, this force user would have to have power unlike any other. As we saw in the movies with Jabba the Hutt and the Clone Wars series with Cad Bane, even non-force-sensitive can be extremely difficult to use a mind trick on. It took multiple powerful Jedi to use Force influence on Cad Bane, let alone another force user who could sense people's 'force signatures.'

We do not yet know the extent of Supreme Leader Snoke's power, but if he were powerful enough, more powerful than Palpatine, Vader, or other Sith lords such as Bane, Malgus, or Revan, he could potentially have the power to have this kind of influence over powerful force users like Kylo Ren.

I do not believe that any ability like this has been demonstrated in the canon universe, and I am not sure about the EU, but I have not found any evidence of these kinds of abilities in my research.

Comment: After looking a fair amount on Wookieepedia, I can't find any indication that it is possible to impersonate someone through the Force. Best bet is probably to use a Jedi mind trick like you suggested. "I am that other person you're looking for."

Comment: In all of the examples I've seen regarding the Jedi mind trick, it seems that the individual being "tricked" needs to be in somewhat close proximity, which would potentially negate its use in this particular application.  I don't recall an instance, but has this ability been seen to work over longer distances (i.e., ship-to-ship, or longer)?

Comment: As there doesn't seem to be any example of the proposed impersonation ability, I'm going to provisionally accept this answer unless something more "ferrocrete" can be provided.

Comment: In the answer provided by @Phyneas to the question [What is the full extent of the power of the Jedi mind trick?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97629/what-is-the-full-extent-of-the-power-of-the-jedi-mind-trick), as well as some of the information in the [Long-distance Mind Trick](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51883/long-distance-mind-trick) question, it would seem that there is evidence (at least in Legends) that the mind trick _can_ be used across greater distances than face-to-face encounters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't care if the books aren't part of this disfigured cannon. In the book-the Crystal Star, Luke changes his appearance to everyone-but controls it for Han, to make it easier on him.

Comment: Thanks for that reference.  As I specified that I was accepting canon and legends references, this is a great example.  I haven't read the book you mentioned, so I might have to check it out next time I have a chance.